# separate_stains output of one channel and conversion to grayscale

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am using color deconvolution to identify the red pixels in a histology image, but the output values from `separate_stains` appear to be in a format of both positive and negative values rather than a grayscale 0-255 value scale.
What is the format of the output and how can I transform it to the common value scales of a grayscale image?

Answer (score 0):

The linear algebra involved in stain unmixing can produce negative values. Obviously negative stain densities do not exist. These negative values are an artefact of noise, imprecise color definitions, and the unmixing model ignoring light absorption by things other than the two stains you defined.

It is safe to set negative pixels to zero.

Comment: Upon checking the range of the values on the output of the deconvolution ('separate_stains') I see that the maximum value is negative (~-0.2 in the image I provided you in the other discussion). What does that mean? Does it indicate that the 'hax_from_rgb' param I'm using is providing the deconvolution the wrong matrix values for these stains?

Comment: @Assafb: Is that true for all channels, for only for one of the channels? Logically, having two stains, you'd expect only two meaningful channels, it's possible that you are getting a third channel containing residues, and it's possible that this channel is all negative. Nonetheless, the stain unmixing functionality in skimage.color doesn't take background intensity into account, and therefore seems incorrect to me. Also, the stain color definitions used (e.g. those encoded into the matrix returned by `hax_from_rgb`) likely don't match your particular experimental conditions.

Comment: I'll write more about this later.

Comment: Yes, all three channels are all negative. @CrisLuengo

Comment: @Assafb: That makes no sense. I don’t have experience with the functions you’re using here, so cannot verify their correctness. Negative values should be fairly rare in the stain unmixing process if stain definitions used are good approximations.